# How to grant the ability to only see a particular column but not another column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

All,

Background: I am using the Chinook database. The schema for that database can be found [here](https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema)

My task

> Grant rogerbell1 the ability to only see the artist name but not the artist id. Show that this is the case using select statements attempting to show the names of the top 5 artists, and the names and artist ids of the top 5 artists.

I am receiving the following when I try to revoke the ArtistId column of the table. What am I doing wrong?

[What I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghgTo.jpg)

I want to be able to revoke the 'ArtistId' column so I can only see the 'Name' column of this table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `revoke select ...` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html

Comment: Maybe take a look at views